# How to display Excel table (data validation list) based on the value in previous cell- multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, list

I have multiple tables with various data that is related to each other in Excel (example here: [Tables in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzelZ.png))

I have named all the tables (example here: [Tables' names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaWfB.png))
And I have created lists from these tables for easier calling them in Data Validation if needed (example here: [Tables' lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXI4a.png)).

What I would like to achieve is a sheet, where users would be able to keep selecting options based on previous choices. Like in this particular case, they would need first to select country (example here: [country selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp3Ik.png)), then based on the selected country, select food assigned to this country (example here: [country specific food selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etSOx.png)), and finally, depending on what food has been selected, select more particular type of earlier selected food (example: [food details selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G3Om.png)).

Problem I have is with the last selection. I could loop it with "ifs", but when I have more tables (example has only few, the real life scenario has more of them), data validation field allows only certain length of text and all the "ifs" exceed it, so I can't get a formula there.

Is there a way to create a short formula fitting in data validation that would:

1. check what has been selected in earlier cell
2. check to which table it belongs
3. what next table should be displayed as a drop down list?

Thanks a lot!
N

Comment: I think your data is way too fragmented. Have you considered putting everything in one table? A single table with a column for "food" (the specific food item), "food type" (burgers, fries, bagels...) and country of origin. Then pull data from that. What you have now is going to be a nightmare to maintain in my opinion. When you have one table and want to add a food item, all you need to do is add one row to it. Whereas what you do now, you would have to update multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! This is just an example to picture the issue. Data I need to use cannot be put in one table unfortunately due to all the dependencies between elements. I know it's a nightmare. I am hoping that there's some smart head or an absolute Excel expert that would know the trick to make an if loop or similar that would be short enough to fit in the data validation line.

Comment: I posted my solution to your problem. BUT...if the only issue is that your formula is too long, I'm sure I could make a VBA wrapper for it which would fit wherever you need. Do you actually have the formula and can you post it in your question? I'll try to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you can't put everything in one table but I already made this and I'm not going to throw it away. It's not really an answer to your question but rather a different approach to your problem and it does work.

**Make a table called "data" on a worksheet also called "data", looking like this:**

| food | foodType | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cod | fish | UK |
| bass | fish | UK |
| curly | chips | UK |
| thick cut | chips | UK |
| wedges | chips | UK |
| chocolate | pudding | UK |
| bread | pudding | UK |
| banana | pudding | UK |
| cheesburger | burgers | US |
| fisburger | burgers | US |
| beef | burgers | US |
| steak | fries | US |
| crinkle | fries | US |
| shoestring | fries | US |
| sesame | bagels | US |
| sweet onion | bagels | US |
| plain | bagels | US |
| Ruskie | pierogi | PL |
| Z grzybami | pierogi | PL |
| Z serem | pierogi | PL |
| Tradycyjny | bigos | PL |
| Mloda Kapusta | bigos | PL |
| Schabowy | kotlet | PL |
| Mielony | kotlet | PL |
| Rybny | kotlet | PL |

**Insert new VBA module and paste this code into it:**

```vba
Function uniqueValuesFromColumn(ByVal rng As Range, Optional ByVal colNum As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal visibleOnly As Boolean = False) As Collection
    Set uniqueValuesFromColumn = New Collection
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        Dim val As String
        val = r.Cells(1, colNum)
        If (Not r.EntireRow.Hidden And visibleOnly) Or Not visibleOnly Then
            On Error Resume Next
                uniqueValuesFromColumn.Add val, val
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next r
End Function

Function stringFromCollection(ByVal col As Collection, ByVal separator As String) As String
    Dim val As Variant
    For Each val In col
        stringFromCollection = stringFromCollection & val & separator
    Next val
    stringFromCollection = Left(stringFromCollection, Len(stringFromCollection) - 1)
End Function

Function updateValidation()
    Worksheets("data").Cells.Validation.Delete
    Dim countryValidation As String, foodTypeValidation As String, foodValidation As String
    
    countryValidation = stringFromCollection(uniqueValuesFromColumn(Worksheets("data").Range("data"), 3, True), ",")
    Worksheets("data").Range("I1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=countryValidation
    
    foodTypeValidation = stringFromCollection(uniqueValuesFromColumn(Worksheets("data").Range("data"), 2, True), ",")
    Worksheets("data").Range("K1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=foodTypeValidation
    
    foodValidation = stringFromCollection(uniqueValuesFromColumn(Worksheets("data").Range("data"), 1, True), ",")
    Worksheets("data").Range("M1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=foodValidation
End Function
```

**Then insert following code into the "data" sheet module:**

[image: data sheet help]

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo cleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Worksheets("data")
        Select Case Target
            Case .Range("I1")
                If .Range("I1") = vbNullString Then
                    .ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
                    .ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
                Else
                    .ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=.Range("I1")
                End If
                .Range("K1").Clear
                .Range("M1").Clear
            Case .Range("K1")
                If .Range("K1") = vbNullString Then
                    .ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
                Else
                    .ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=.Range("K1")
                End If
                .Range("M1").Clear
        End Select
    End With
cleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    updateValidation
End Sub
```

**And finally insert this code into the "ThisWorkbook" module:**

[image: workbook module help]

```vba
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    updateValidation
End Sub
```

Now just save the workbook as .xlsm, close it and reopen it. The cells with validation are I1, K1 and M1 on the "data" worksheet.